# Header breaks a apart when resizing browser window

Tags: css, html, layout

I've got a simple page with a header element consisting of a logo image within an anchor tag nested in a h1 element and a nav element with 4 links. Below that I've got two  elements each holding an image and text. I'm wondering why my header breaks apart when I resize the browser window, and why the text is not wrap around their respect images and landing to the right of them. I've also noticed that when I hover passed the logo there's a slight area where it is still a link where it shouldn't be. I'd really appreciate any assistance here, as I'm looking to understand what's happening under the hood with the css.

http://s27.postimg.org/7eyff3ivn/header_break1.png

http://s28.postimg.org/fwg9lohjh/header_break2.png

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Acme</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <meta name="description" content="">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css">
</head>

<body>

      <header>
    <h1><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Respond"></a></h1>

        <nav>   
           <ul>
            <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
           </ul>
        </nav>

    </header>

    <section class="first">

        <h2>Image 1</h2>

        <figure>    
            <img src="images/featured.png" alt="Image 1" />
        </figure>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et eum vocibus neglegentur, id nisl quidam<br>
            melius nam. Agam inani vel ei, reque putent oportere qui ad. Cum<br> 
            autem veniam in, soluta everti volumus no ius. Utinam tritani est ex,<br> 
            mei decore putent vidisse ne, an justo nulla eirmod duo. Te liber<br> 
            libris adolescens eos, id regione gloriatur neglegentur pri. Mei sanctus deleniti repudiandae<br> 
            at, sit tritani fabulas dissentias et, salutandi vituperata vim ex.</p>

    </section>

    <section class="second">

        <h2>Image 2</h2>

        <figure>
           <img src="images/featured.png" alt="Image 2" />
        </figure>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et eum vocibus neglegentur, id nisl quidam
            melius nam. Agam inani vel ei, reque putent oportere qui ad. Cum<br> 
            autem veniam in, soluta everti volumus no ius. Utinam tritani est ex,<br> 
            mei decore putent vidisse ne, an justo nulla eirmod duo. Te liber<br> 
            libris adolescens eos, id regione gloriatur neglegentur pri. Mei sanctus deleniti repudiandae<br> 
            at, sit tritani fabulas dissentias et, salutandi vituperata vim ex.</p>

    </section>

    <footer>    
        <p id="copyright">&copy; 2014 ACME</p>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/* Reset
------------------------------------------------------------ */
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html { overflow-y: scroll;}
body { background:#ffffff; font-size: 16px; color: #666666; font-family: Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;}
ol, ul { list-style: none; margin: 0;}
ul li { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
h1 { margin-bottom: 10px; color: #111111;}  
a, img { outline: none; border:none; color: #000; font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase;}
p { margin: 0 0 10px; line-height: 1.4em; font-size: 1.2em;}
img { display: block; margin-bottom: 10px;}
aside { font-style: italic; font-size: 0.9em;}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section { 
    display: block;
    }

/*  Structure   */
body {
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial;
    background: white;
    color: #555;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black; 
}

/* Logo H1 */
header h1 {
  float: left;
}

header h1 a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: .5em;
  margin-left: 5.5em;
  width: 25%;
}

/* Navigation*/

nav {
  width: 75%;
  overflow: auto;
}

ul {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 20em;

}

ul li {
  float: left;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  padding: 2px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

ul li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #6FC36E;
}
/* Content*/
section {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0.625em auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

section h2 {
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

section img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.first {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.first figure {
  width: 75%;
}

.second {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.second figure {
  width: 75%;
}


/* Footer*/
footer {
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This is where you use http://jsfiddle.net to show your issue

Comment: Why are you expecting the text to wrap to the right of the image? There isn't any css to do that

Comment: Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YV8tu/ the page is doing what it's supposed with the given css, I am not sure why you are expecting it to behave any different

Comment: Yes, I should've used jsfiddle or codepen, I'm quite familiar with both and use them plenty. I just didn't. I'll be sure to use them though from here on out.

Comment: Huangism, I know the text is not wrapping around the image, I can see that perfectly well, and yes the css is doing what's it's supposed to, but that's not the behavior I'm looking to achieve with the page as I stated in my question. Nonetheless, I'm asking for help here. If I'm not mistaken, I believe that's what the purpose of StackOverflow existence is all about. I'm looking to learn by understanding the underpinnings of what I'm doing wrong. I don't want to just know "solution" to the problem because I'm more interested in the way of arriving at it.

Comment: Be specific about a particular issue per question. You are giving us a page and you are saying there is x number of things wrong with the page. Not many people will debug the entire page for you. Separate the nav issue by updating the question and ask another/more question about the others. If the answer you get solves that particular issue then check mark it. In fact you can delete most of the codes that are unrelated to the nav and jsut present the specific issue/code

Answer (score 0):

This answer only addresses the problems you are having with your navigation.

I would remove the following properties from `ul` in your css.

```
float: right;
margin-right: 20em;
```

You don't need to float the menu to the right and the margin decreases the available space for your menu. The 75% width you set in your CSS should do enough to constrain your menu size.

The only wrapping of your nav that will occur is when the width of nav is less than the width of the elements in your menu. If you want to prevent this you can enlarge the width of the nav or take a different approach.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep at it.